# Trying to convert string array to int but does not work in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to solve the *Project Euler Problem #16*: https://projecteuler.net/problem=16. It requires me to sum up every digits from the result of 2^1000.

I iterate through the string (converted from `double` type) by treating the string as an array. However when I try to convert string digit back to `int`, I always got error.

I tried with `stoi`, It prompts me `"no matching function for call to 'atoi'"`. I also tried with `stringstream` for conversion, it still did not work.

Please see my following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex> // pow
#include <string> // to_string C++ 11

const double NUM = pow(2, 1000);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    //printf("%.0f\n", NUM); // Remove decimal digits
    auto str = std::to_string(NUM);
    std::string str_trim = str.substr(0, str.length()-7);
    std::cout << str_trim << std::endl; // 2^1000 in string

    for (int i = 0; i <= str_trim.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << str_trim[i] << std::endl;
        sum = sum + str_trim[i];
        std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Remove the extra information. What is the main issue? You can't convert a number written as a string to an int, right?

Comment: Anyway, your approach to the question is wrong. Since you need to add the digits, you need to be able to figure out the exact value of 2^1000. As far as I remember, even a double won't be able to store 2^1000. And more importantly, you will lose a lot of information in form of digits while storing it as a double, and so you can't add the digits for the correct answer.

Comment: The code "std::cout << str_trim << std::endl;" seems print out the answer (over 300 digits). I think it should be OK to work with double.

Comment: For `2^1000` the approach, amazingly enough, works fine. The reason is that ieee754 double format will lose precision by considering missing bits to be zeros... and in 2^1000 all bits (except MSB) **are** zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pure coincidence this approach will work fine on most compilers for 2^1000 because the rounding done by IEEE754 double format (the most common format for floating point numbers in C++) will drop bits by considering them to be zeros (and in `2^1000` those bits are indeed zeros).

To sum up the digit you can just iterate over the chars and execute

```
total += s[i] - '0';
```

using the fact that in C++ `chars` are indeed small integers.

Comment: Smartypants, plus one! (So I can recover some dignity: C++ does not insist on IEEE754, so your approach will only work on some compilers.)

Comment: @Bathsheba: true... with "some" defined as 99.975% :-D ... and by the way I had to try with Python to be sure that int(pow(2.,1000))==2**1000 before posting. Never thought about this before (i solved that EP problem the "standard" way).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert `std::string` to `int` use `std::stoi`. C++ also has a few other functions for other types: `std::stoi, std::stol, std::stoll, std::stoul, std::stoull, std::stof, std::stod, std::stold`

---

Still no C++ type can hold 2^1000 so you can't use standard types and standard functions for such values.

Comment: Actually, for a lucky coincidence, a double-precision number on most C++ compilers can hold 2^1000 exactly (the reason is that the dropped bits will be considered to be zeros, and they're indeed zeros in 2^1000).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to extract the digits from the `NUM` your answer will be incorrect:

`const double NUM = pow(2, 1000);`

cannot be relied upon to store the number exactly.

An alternative way of solving this problem is to evaluate 2 to the 1000th power in binary (the result is simple: it is 1 followed by 1,000 zeros). Your problem is then reduced to converting that back to base 10 and summing the digits; perhaps even doing that part simultaneously. But you will not be able to use any of the built-in types to represent that number. That is what makes this problem interesting.